# Laravel rule to checking length is not equal to N

Tags: laravel, variable-length

We have defined some rules in laravel but we need rule in which length of string should not be 5.

code is given below.

```
$rules = array(
'id' => 'required|numeric|digits_between:7,8'
);
```

current rule is length would be in between 7 and 8 but i need to modify it to length should be anything but not equal to 5. Please help to resolve.

Comment: I can't find something like that in the documentation. You can [create a custom validator](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#custom-validation-rules) to solve this.

Comment: So it can be any number other than 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never forget regexs :)
Here is an example that prevents length =5, not_regex is used cause d{} cant be negated so i consider this the optimal and shortest solution

```
 'id' =>'required|not_regex:/\b\d{5}\b/',
```

hope it helps